# Conflict when using django-simple-history with django-computedfields libraries together

Tags: django

In my django app I have a model with some computed fields, i have used django-computedfields to achive that. Now i am trying to add django-simple-history to my model, but aparently there is a conflict when using these two django libraries. When making migrations I am getting the following error.

```
computedfields.resolver.ResolverException: <class 'arbolsaf.models.HistoricalSpeciesModel'> is not a subclass of ComputedFieldsModel
```

This is my code (I am not showing all fields in the model):

```
from computedfields.models import ComputedFieldsModel, computed, compute
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

class SpeciesModel(BasicAuditModel, ComputedFieldsModel):

    history = HistoricalRecords()
    
    VALUES_CHOICES = (
        ("ninguno", "Ninguno"),
        ("bajo", "Bajo"),
        ("medio", "Medio"),
        ("alto", "Alto"),
    )
        
    cod_esp = models.CharField(_("Código especie"), max_length=50, unique=True)
    taxonid_wfo = models.CharField(_("Taxon ID WFO"), max_length=50)
    nombre_comun = models.CharField(_("Nombre común"), max_length=255)
    nombre_cientifico = models.CharField(_("Nombre científico"), max_length=255)
    nombre_cientifico_completo = models.CharField(_("Nombre científico completo"), max_length=255)
    familia = models.ForeignKey("arbolsaf.FamilyModel", verbose_name=_("Familia"), on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    genero = models.ForeignKey("arbolsaf.GenderModel", verbose_name=_("Género"), on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    epiteto = models.CharField(_("Epíteto"), max_length=50)
    
    variedad_subespecie = models.CharField(_("Variedad/Subespecie"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    autor = models.CharField(_("Autor"), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    nativa = models.BooleanField(_("Nativa?"))

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'arbolsaf_species'
        managed = True
        ordering = ["nombre_cientifico"]
        verbose_name = 'Especie'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Especies'
```

Answer (score 0):

So the reason this is happening is because SimpleHistory is including your computed fields in the historical model it creates. When this happens, computedfields sees that the historical model has computed fields, but doesn't extend ComputedFieldsModel, so it whines about it.

Way around this: use the `excluded_fields` argument on the `HistoricalRecords` field on your `SpeciesModel` model.

```
class SpeciesModel(BasicAuditModel, ComputedFieldsModel):

    history = HistoricalRecords(excluded_fields=['COMPUTED_FIELD_1_NAME', 'COMPUTED_FIELD_2_NAME'])
```

Doing this will prevent the historical model from including your computed fields.